# Layout page in ASP.NET doesn't load the CSS

Tags: css, asp.net, visual-studio

I have an ASP.NET project in Razor, the CSS page is `main.css` with this code:

```
.body {       
      margin: 0px;
      padding: 0px;
}

.header {
     padding: 0px;
     background-color : red ;
}

.header_logotipo {
         border: 1px solid;
         flex: 0 0 50%;
}
```

The `_layout.cshtml` is:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>
    <title> Micro Forum </title>
    <link href ="~/styles/main.css" rel="stylesheet"  type="text/css" runat="server">

   </head>
    <body>
    @RenderPage("~/inc/_header.cshtml")
    @RenderBody()
    @RenderPage("~/inc/_footer.cshtml")
   </body>
   </html>
```

And the default Razor page is :

```
 @{
    Layout = "~/inc/_layout.cshtml"; 
 }
 <div>Contenido de la Pagina</div>
```

The output in IIS doesn't show any formatting as defined in `main.css`:

[image]

The page Main.CSS are in the ~/styles path and _layout.cshtml are in the ~/inc path

What am I loosing or writing wrong? Thanks for any help

Alejandro

Comment: don't think you need the runat server

Comment: I have try deleting the runat="server" , nothing changes

Comment: Is the path to the css file correct? Try this: <link href="~/styles/main.css" rel="stylesheet">.